# NullPointerException when getting WindowManager from Service under Robolectric

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I'm writing a test for a `Service` using Robolectric 2.4:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        Robolectric.buildService(MyService.class)
            .create()
            .get()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

}
```

When `getSystemService` is called on the `Service`, a `NullPointerException` is thrown as shown below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:519)
    at MyServiceTest.someTest(MyServiceTest.java:10)
```

The problem doesn't happen when I call `getSystemService` on `Robolectric.application` or a `Robolectric`-made `Activity`; it seems to be a problem specific to services.

In the actual tests, my service is trying to get the `WindowManager` using itself as the `Context`, so I can't just use `Robolectric.application` to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Context, no ContextWrapper.

You have to attach a Context before your create a Service instance. So just call `attach()` before `create()`.

So it will look like this:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        Robolectric.buildService(UpdateService.class)
            .attach()
            .create()
            .get()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

}
```

**Update for Robolectric >= 3.3**
In Robolectric 3.3 attach is now deprecated and will be removed in 3.4 ([see api doc](http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.3/org/robolectric/android/controller/ComponentController.html#attach--)). So since 3.3 you can drop the attach call (thanks to @inder).

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void someTest() {
        Robolectric.buildService(UpdateService.class)
            .create()
            .get()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    }

}
```

Comment: attach() is now deprecated